# How are the vitreous humour and aqueous humour of the eye, connected?

Tags: eyes, human-eye

My question is regarding the biological nature of the separation between the vitreous humour and aqueous humour of the human (or mammal) eye. What connects the two in terms of the passive transport of proteins between the two? Is there a single membrane?

If so what is the name of this membrane and is it the only thing separating the aqueous from the vitreous? What is the anatomical difference between the aqueous and the vitreous?

Apologies, I am far from a biologist.

Specifically what sort of transport is arrow 9 in the figure below representing? And is backward transport (from the aqueous to the vitreous) possible?

Any links to papers detailing this mechanism would be highly appreciated, I can only find references to experimental readings of concentrations, but nothing about the transport process itself.

[image]

Comment: I do apologise for that. However to me I don't really see the difference, the main body of my question asked about the transport of molecules, I merely drew more attention to that part of my question. I would say previously it was vaguely phrased, as, which I previously mentioned, this is not my field, I was attempting to make up for that, I'm sorry to have offended however.

Comment: Retracted comment - sorry! +1 had to make a slight edit before I could upvote again. Feel free to roll back :)

Comment: You have changed the question, so my answer looks unrelated. I'd suggest roll question back and ask others in separate question.

Comment: @Ilan, will do. Here is a link:
http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/how-do-drugs-or-other-molecules-move-between-the-vitreous-humour-and-aqueous-h

Comment: @Ilan Well the question might have sounded different but the OP asks if there is any connection in the sense of exchange of matter between the two "humours". This doesn't require a different question. OP just clarified their actual intention. You can edit your answer to add if there is any material exchange between them or not. Your answer is still fine.

Comment: @Freeman Keep the actual title of the question.. Add details in the body so that Ilan's answer remains pertinent.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I've added a little detail regarding the membrane. I believe IIans answer is still very useful. I would however like to know more regarding the actual process.

Comment: @Freeman edit the question.. This doesn't need a new question

Comment: @WYSIWYG Apologies for the confusion here.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I added the clarification to the answer, but I should mention that a question is too broad to answer in a format it is asked.

Comment: @Ilan You can tell that to the OP in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't be confused by the word "humour": the vitreous body is presented in birth and has very low "exchange" rate of its components, while aqueous is in constant turnover.

Secondly, the vitreous is an organ-like structure and is *separated* from other eye structures by [its membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitreous_membrane), while aqueous is fluid produced by ciliary body processes into the posterior chamber and moves  anteriorly throughout the pupil. Aqueous can move posteriorly in a case of trauma, operations and other non-physiologic states.

ADD (after attachment of the image)

I'd correct some things in the scheme - call Vitreous as Vitreous, not Vitreous humour, change arrow pointing at the ciliary body as on the following image, depict the vitreous body membrane as I did.

[image]

In addition learn two terms: Cloquet canal and Berger's space.

Number 9 shows a vitreo-aqueous route which will follow blood, drugs injected to the vitreous (not an only route), etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so are you saying that as soon as a component has managed to pass through the vitreous membrane it is quickly removed by the aqueous? Would you mind looking at this diagram in my edit? I don't understand arrow 9, what sort of transport does this represent?

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much for adding details.

Comment: Since 2015, have you been able to answer your question "Specifically what sort of transport is arrow 9 in the figure below representing?"

Comment: @PeterBernhard 9 had to show drainage pass to the anterior chamber angler (number-arrow 4)